# how to get the module of a vector? Absolute value

Tags: math, vector

How to get module of a vector like: V = (5, 3).
I want the return value to be positive.
And if the vector is 3d? like: V2 = (5,4,3). What's the formula to get it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the value that way: (it will be always positive)

Value = square root (first element^2 + second element^2 ,... )